# replace several instances of a pattern in a one line string in OS X

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I have following string:

```
<li>something</li><li>lorem <a href="URL">link</a>ipsum</li><li>dolor sit</li><li>something</li><li>lorem <a href="URL">link</a>ipsum</li><li></li>
```

With sed I want to delete all instances of `<li>lorem <a href="URL">link</a>ipsum</li>` in this line and every following line.

I have the following command which would remove all instances of `<li>lorem ipsum</li>`

```
sed -i "" 's:<li>lorem[^<]*</li>::g'
```

but unfortunately it cannot handle (ignore) the `<a href="URL">link</a>` tag within the replacement pattern.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
AleV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably better off using `xml` parsers for this. But if you must then here is a way of doing it in `perl`.

```
perl -pe 's,(?<=</li>)<li>lorem.+?</li>(?=<li>),,g' inputFile
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
<li>something</li><li>lorem <a href="URL">link</a>ipsum</li><li>dolor sit</li><li>something</li><li>lorem <a href="URL">link</a>ipsum</li><li></li>
$ perl -pe 's,(?<=</li>)<li>lorem.+?</li>(?=<li>),,g' file
<li>something</li><li>dolor sit</li><li>something</li><li></li>
```

Comment: Thanks, but computer says no. On my OS X machine this perl code unfortunately didn't work. I'm not into perl, so can't find the error...And using an XML parser is not the plan for the moment. I'd rather use a command line solution like sed or perl (or whatever does the job).

Comment: @AleV I added a test, but not sure why it won't work on your system unless your sample data is not a true representation of your real data.

Comment: There was a mistake on my side when testing your code. Thanks for your effort! It helped me to find a working hack to solve the issue.

Comment: @AleV: Mark this answer as accepted as a token for appreciation of the efforts that have been put it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this (sed), but I can't test it on OS X:

```
sed  -E 's:<li>lorem (<[^>]*>\S*){2}</li>::g' file
```

input:

```
<li>something</li><li>lorem <a href="URL">link</a>ipsum</li><li>dolor sit</li><li>something</li><li>lorem <a href="URL">link</a>ipsum</li><li></li>
```

desired output:

```
<li>something</li><li>dolor sit</li><li>something</li><li></li>
```

my output:

```
<li>something</li><li>dolor sit</li><li>something</li>
```

As you can see, there is a small difference at the end. So parsing [html](/questions/tagged/html) or [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) by [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) is **not** a good idea. You can get a solution for one line, but doesn't work for the next.

Comment: Hi Endoro. What is your choice of solution to parse html and xml?

Comment: for HTML I use a shell script (not good :)) and for json [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (good :P).